# Invalid create() invocation with prisma

Tags: typescript, prisma

I undestand that it says env variable not found however in a seperate example I do a similar create and it connects to the db fine. Heres the func and model

```
model sdk_error {
  view_id   String   @id
  message   String
  timestamp DateTime
}


const errorIngestionHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const time = new Date('November 8, 2022, 12:00:00');
  const errorModel = await prisma.sdk_error.create({
    data: {
      view_id: '1234',
      message: 'this is a test',
      timestamp: time,
    },
  });

  const ret = await prisma.sdk_error.findUnique({
    where: {
      view_id: errorModel.view_id,
    },
  });

  res.send(ret);
};
```

Trying to test my request handler, I want to create a test input to compare against. The issue I encounter is with the create function producing this error
Invalid `prisma.sdk_error.create()` invocation in
C:\Users\cmb\vlly\vlly-api\src\v1\ingestion\error.ts:6:45

```
  3 //Errors
  4 const errorIngestionHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  5   const time = new Date('November 8, 2022, 12:00:00');
→ 6   const errorModel = await prisma.sdk_error.create(
error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:12
   |
11 |   provider = "mysql"
12 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
```

Validation Error Count: 1

```
  4 | const errorIngestionHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  5 |   const time = new Date('November 8, 2022, 12:00:00');
> 6 |   const errorModel = await prisma.sdk_error.create({
    |                      ^
  7 |     data: {
  8 |       view_id: '1234',
  9 |       message: 'this is a test',

  at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34316:13)
  at node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34737:25
  at PrismaClient._executeRequest (node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35301:22)
  at PrismaClient._request (node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35273:16)
  at errorIngestionHandler (src/v1/ingestion/error.ts:6:22)
```

● API Endpoint test › creates new row in error table

```
Invalid `prisma.sdk_error.create()` invocation in
C:\Users\cmb\vlly\vlly-api\src\v1\ingestion\error.ts:6:45

  3 //Errors
  4 const errorIngestionHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  5   const time = new Date('November 8, 2022, 12:00:00');
→ 6   const errorModel = await prisma.sdk_error.create(
error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:12
   |
11 |   provider = "mysql"
12 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
   |

Validation Error Count: 1

  4 | const errorIngestionHandler = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  5 |   const time = new Date('November 8, 2022, 12:00:00');
> 6 |   const errorModel = await prisma.sdk_error.create({
    |                      ^
  7 |     data: {
  8 |       view_id: '1234',
  9 |       message: 'this is a test',

  at RequestHandler.handleRequestError (node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34316:13)
  at node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:34737:25
  at PrismaClient._executeRequest (node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35301:22)
  at PrismaClient._request (node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/index.js:35273:16)
  at errorIngestionHandler (src/v1/ingestion/error.ts:6:22)
```

● API Endpoint test › creates new row in error table

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

  20 |       .expect('Not implemented');
  21 |   });
> 22 |   it('creates new row in error table', async () => {
     |   ^
  23 |     const time =  new Date('November 8, 2022, 12:00:00');
  24 |     const expected = {
  25 |       view_id: '1234',

  at src/v1/ingestion/error.test.ts:22:3
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/v1/ingestion/error.test.ts:8:1)
```

Edit: added entire error stack trace for more context

Comment: Can you share the full error message stack trace?

Comment: Do you *have* a `DATABASE_URL` env var?

Comment: yes in my other testfile, it connects to prisma using the same database_url

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change the name of the model from sdk_error -> sdkError. Seems like the underscore breaks the name of the model.